# if statement with a limit php

Tags: php, if-statement

I made this to check my class schedule to remind me when there is no class. I set it on a cron job to check every hour, but my issue is that when there is no class I keep getting alerts all day and can't stop it unless I disable the cron job. **What I would like to know is how I can limit this to only 5 alerts for the entire day?**

```
$source = file_get_contents($website);
preg_match('#<classtime>(.*?)</classtime>#', $source, $match);

    if (strlen($match[1])<32) {
        mail('XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net', 'REMINDER!', 'No Class');
    }
    else

    if (strlen($match[1])>32) {
        mail('XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net', 'REMINDER!', 'No Class');
    }

    else {
        echo "Check Class Schedule";
    }
```

Comment: *(sidenote)* consider using SimpleXml to parse the XML over using Regex. Consider to check `if === 32 then echo else mail` to remove the duplication. Also, replace the magic number 32 with something meaningful.

Comment: To make things interesting, do you mean 5 within any 24 hour period or 5 between midnight and midnight? I think you mean the latter, but the former would be more fun.

Comment: @Blowski yes 24hr period would be nice.

Comment: Done - please see answer below.

Comment: What answer did you go with in the end?

Answer (score 0):

save a text file (or use a database) to update how many times that day an alert was sent, 
and if it is greater than 5    dont send the alert

Answer (score 0):

Store the count of sent alerts in a file somewhere, increment it each time you check, and don't send alerts if the count's > 5. After midnight rolls around, reset the count to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and simple answer is create a file, you read and write to. eg.

```
while (( $fp = fopen ($counterfile,"r+")) == false)
{ usleep(5);}
       while (!flock($fp,2))
{ usleep(5); }
$data = fread($fp,filesize($counterfile));
if (rewind($fp)!=0)
{
        $data++;
        fwrite($fp,$data,strlen($data));
}
flock($fp,3);
fclose($fp);
```

If you use this each time you encounter a "No class" senario, once it reaches 5, if the read says 5, dont send any more messages. Then to keep it simple, at midnight have a cron job to echo "0" into the file.

Comment: Thank you! i am just wondering if i simply place this into my code or do i have to add my code into this one

Comment: Either to be honest. that reads and increments the counter, you can add your code to it, or it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Checks for no more than 5 emails in the last 24 hour period. Could be massively improved and it needs error handling, but it should work:

```
$log_file = 'log.txt';
$log = file_get_contents( $log_file );
$timestamps = array_splice( explode( PHP_EOL, $log ), -5, 1 );
if ( count( $timestamps > 5 ) )
    {
    if ( end( $timestamps ) == '' )
        {
        array_pop( $timestamps );
        }
    $fifth_from_last_email = ($timestamps[0]);
    $time_24_hours_ago = time() - 3600 * 24;
    if ( $fifth_from_last_email < $time_24_hours_ago )
        {
        $fp = fopen( $log_file, 'a+' );
        fwrite( $fp, time() . PHP_EOL );
        fclose( $fp );
        mail( 'XXXXXXXXXX@txt.att.net', 'REMINDER!', 'No Class' );
        }
    }
```